# Displaying multiple images using QML in GridView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I've used the file dialog to select multiple images like this :

```
    FileDialog{
        id: uploadFiles
        title: "Please choose images for dimple detection"
        selectMultiple: true
        nameFilters: [ "Image files (*.jpg *.png *.tif)", "All files (*)" ]
        onAccepted: {}
        }
```

I know I can reach the file paths using:

```
uplaodFile.fileUrls
```

but how can I display them in a Flickable item using GridView ?

**Edit :**
This the full code of the page ...

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import "../controls"
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3
Item {
property bool isGridViewVisiable: false
Rectangle {
    id: bgHome
    color: "#2c313c"
    anchors.fill: parent

    Flickable{
        id: flickableUpload
        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true

        Text {
            id: titleResults
            x: 249
            width: 347
            height: 141
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Upload the images to here please :)")
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.top: parent.top
            font.pixelSize: 25
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            anchors.verticalCenterOffset: -110
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 8
            anchors.topMargin: 59
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            font.family: "Arial"
            font.bold: true
            minimumPointSize: 15
            minimumPixelSize: 16
            fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
        }
        UploadBtn{
            id:uploadBtn
            x: 285
            y: 220
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            btnIconSource: "../../images/svg_images/upload-icon.svg"
            onPressed: {
                uploadFiles.open()
            }
            // opening a file dialog in order to upload the images
            FileDialog{
                id: uploadFiles
                title: "Please choose images for dimple detection"
                selectMultiple: true
                nameFilters: [ "Image files (*.jpg *.png *.tif)", "All files (*)" ]
                onAccepted: {
                    isGridViewVisiable = true
                }
            }
            Component {
                id: nameDelegate
                Column {
                    Image {
                        id: delegateImage
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: delegateText.horizontalCenter
                        source: model; width: 256; height: 256; smooth: true
                        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                    }
                    Text {
                        id: delegateText
                        text: model.name; font.pixelSize: 24
                    }
                }
            }
            GridView{
                id:gridView
                visible: isGridViewVisiable
                anchors.fill: parent
                model:uploadFiles.fileUrls
                delegate: nameDelegate
                clip: true
            }
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{}
    }
}
```

This the full page that I will add to a content loader in the main qml file

PS:
the upload button is a customized button

Comment: Did you try this in your GridView: `model: uploadFiles.fileUrls`?

Comment: I'll check out how to use it.
also I would appreciate it , if you give an example with using it with File Dialogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uploadFiles.fileUrls` is an array of filenames. So you can use that as a model for your `GridView`.

```
GridView {
    model: uploadFiles.fileUrls

    delegate: Image {
        source: modelData
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

It turns out there was a problem with my original answer, as well as with the code that you were trying.

First of all, you're making your `GridView` a child of your `UploadBtn`. Did you intend that? I think that will be too small of a space to draw your images.

But more importantly, the part that I was wrong about is that `fileUrls` is not an array of strings. It's a `list<url>`. I assumed QML would be smart enough to treat that the same as an array, or maybe implicitly convert it to an array if needed. But apparently I was wrong. So we'll just have to use it a little differently.

```
    Flickable{
        ...

        UploadBtn {
            id:uploadBtn
            ...

            FileDialog{
                ...
            }
            Component {
                id: nameDelegate
                Column {
                    Image {
                        ...

                        // Access the list by index
                        source: uploadFiles.fileUrls[index]
                    }
                    Text {
                        ...

                        text: uploadFiles.fileUrls[index]
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Move GridView outside of UploadBtn
        GridView {
            ...

            // Just use the length of the list as our model
            model: uploadFiles.fileUrls.length
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried  GridView{
                    id:gridView
                    visible: isGridViewVisiable
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    model:uploadFiles.fileUrls
                    delegate: Image {
                        id: delegateImage
                        source:modelData; width: 256; height: 256; smooth: true
                        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                    }
                    clip: true
                }
and it didn't work or maybe for some reason it's not displaying it in the Flickable item

Comment: The code works fine for me. Can you print out what's in `fileUrls` to see if the paths/filenames are correct?

Comment: qml:
[file:///C:/Users/yoooo/Desktop/FinalProject/pics_dimpels/1.jpg,file:///C:/Users/yoooo/Desktop/Final Project/pics_dimpels/2.png,file:///C:/Users/yoooo/Desktop/Final Project/pics_dimpels/2.tif,file:///C:/Users/yoooo/Desktop/Final Project/pics_dimpels/3.jpg,file:///C:/Users/yoooo/Desktop/Final Project/pics_dimpels/5 - Copy.tif]

here is what it prints out when tried to upload five pictures,
I will edit out the question and put the full code of the page , maybe I'm mixing up items

Comment: If you just create a single Image and manually set the `source` to "file:///C:/Users/yoooo/Desktop/Final Project/pics_dimpels/1.jpg", does it work as expected?

Comment: yes it works but I had to hide the text and button to see them , so I think the problem is that I need to activate the GridView after I load the images then it will work ... 
Do you have any suggestions on how to dynamically activate it after the images have been loaded ?